# How do I remove libraries from the makefile in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, shared-libraries

So I have a c++ game that I compile to an android app using the ndk. I use android studio with gradle to achieve this. I have an `Android.mk` file where I add all my includes and libraries (in the `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` section) such as `SDL2`, `SDL2_image`, `Box2D` and so on. I tried out firebase analytics for a while, but ended up not using it. I had `firebase_analytics` in my android makefile just like the other libraries, and then removed it and its related things when I was done with it. However, when I build my project it gives me an error saying `no rule to make target 'firebase_analytics'`. Why is it still trying to build firebase? I removed it from the file. Maybe it cached something and it's building off of that? I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but it gives me the same error. Anyone know why this is happening (and what I can do to solve it)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show your Android.mk file. I bet it is still lurking in a dependency somewhere.